# Is it possible to support multiple context paths?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot app running with application.properties:

```
server.contextPath=/ctx1
```

I would like to pick a few specific @Controller's @RequestMappings' and
configure them to use a 
different contextPath or have them
map against the root "/" path

I have looked at @Configuration-ing a ServletRegistrationBean but that
doesn't seem to work.

### Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Mike

Comment: I don't sure what you mean, you have different controllers and want them to have different mappings, right?

Answer (score 2):

`server.contextPath` will add url prefix to all controller mappings. You can use `@RequestMapping` in each controller to add their own mapping for each. Like this:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/demo")
public class ThinController {

    @RequestMapping(path = "/hello", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String hello(){
        return "success...";
    }
}
```